# Displaying a ui-router modal without refreshing the parent state

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have added a modalStateProvider to my angular app such that I can easily have modals with their own URLs.

```
// Add support for modalState
app.provider('modalState', [
  '$stateProvider',
  function($stateProvider) {
    var provider = this;
    this.$get = function() {
      return provider;
    };
    this.state = function(stateName, options) {
      var modalInstance;
      $stateProvider.state(stateName, {
        url: options.url,
        onEnter: [
          '$modal', '$state',
          function($modal, $state) {
            modalInstance = $modal.open(options);
            modalInstance.result['finally'](function() {
              modalInstance = null;
              if ($state.$current.name === stateName) {
                $state.go('^');
              }
            });
          }
        ],
        onExit: function() {
          if (modalInstance) {
            modalInstance.close();
          }
        }
      });
    };
  }
]);
```

I then have a state, 'participants', which lists all of the participants in a project:

```
.state('participants', {
  url: '/participants?view&q&order',
  parent: 'feedback',
  reloadOnSearch: false,
  views: {
    'content@feedback': {
      templateUrl: moduleDir + '/participants/participants.html',
      controller: 'feedback.ParticipantsCtrl'
    }
  }
})
```

And, I wish to display a modal for viewing or editing a participant:

```
modalStateProvider.state('participants.view', {
  url: '/:participantId',
  templateUrl: moduleDir + '/participant/participant.html',
  controller: 'feedback.ParticipantCtrl',
});
```

The modal displays and has it's own unique URL as desired.

However, opening the modal from the participants state, the participants state is refreshed in the background (distracting the user and losing their scroll position).

How can I prevent this refreshing?

As a bonus, I would also like to remove the query parameters (view,q,order) from the URL when the modal is opened, and then readd them when it is closed. It does not matter that they cannot be readded to the URL if the user refreshes the modal page. I mention this part of my challenge mainly in case it would affect your answer to the main question above :)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this had nothing to do with me using a modal, and everything to do with the query parameters (`?view&q&order`).

I am unclear on why these lead to a reload, but resolved my issue by changing to:

```
.state('participants', {
  url: '/participants',
  parent: 'feedback',
  reloadOnSearch: false,
  onEnter: ['$stateParams', '$location', function($stateParams, $location) {
    $stateParams.view = $location.$$search.view;
    $stateParams.q = $location.$$search.q;
    $stateParams.order = $location.$$search.order;
  }],
  views: {
    'content@feedback': {
      templateUrl: moduleDir + '/participants/participants.html',
      controller: 'feedback.ParticipantsCtrl'
    }
  }
})
```

This resolves both my initial problem and the bonus question - as it's not part of the state URL, the view/order/q query parameters don't get appended onto the URL of the modal :)